# Adjusting text size to fit tabu column width

Tags: math-mode, columns, tabu, size

I am using `tabu` to create math tables. One of my equations is too long and exceeding the column width of the table, like so:

[image]

How can I make LaTeX automatically adjust the font size of the equation to fit within the column width?

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[british, 11pt, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} to \textwidth{X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c] X[c]}
\toprule
Test & Test & Test & Test & Test\\
\midrule
$r_0(P_2)=\frac{1}{5}$ & $r_1(P_2)=\frac{4}{15}$ & $\begin{aligned}
r_2(P_2)&=\frac{r_2(P_1)}{3} + \frac{r_2(P_4)}{1}\\ 
&=\frac{1}{6}
\end{aligned}$ & $r_3(P_2)=\frac{7}{45}$ & 1\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Related to [How to make equation fit in the column](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/82654/124842) or maybe [How can I auto adjust a equation to appear in the entire page? (Scale to equations, is this exist?)](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35631/124842).